# How to store result calcluated inside two for loops in np array?

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop

I want to iterate through an image and save the calculated distance beetween the restrictive (x,y) pixel and the point (300,600) in the numpy array np_dist. At the moment the result for all dist values is saved in one element of the array. How is it possible to fill the array storing one value per element?

```
dist_arr = np.empty((width, height))
for x in range(0, width): 
    for y in range(0, height): 
        pixel = (x, y) 
        dist = math.sqrt((300 - pixel[0])**2 + (600 - pixel[1])**2) 
        dist_arr[pixel[0], pixel[1]] = dist
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing with your loops:

```
In [26]: width, height = 4,4
    ...: dist_arr = np.empty((width, height))
    ...: for x in range(0, width):
    ...:     for y in range(0, height):
    ...:         dist = math.sqrt((300 - x)**2 + (600 - y)**2)
    ...:         dist_arr[x, y] = dist
    ...: 
In [27]: dist_arr
Out[27]: 
array([[670.82039325, 669.92611533, 669.03213675, 668.1384587 ],
       [670.37377634, 669.47890183, 668.58432527, 667.69004785],
       [669.92835438, 669.03288409, 668.13771036, 667.24283436],
       [669.48412976, 668.58806451, 667.6922944 , 666.79682063]])
```

There are ways of doing this faster, but they work.

Same values with whole-array `numpy` calculation:

```
In [28]: np.sqrt((300-np.arange(4)[:,None])**2 + (600 - np.arange(4))**2)
Out[28]: 
array([[670.82039325, 669.92611533, 669.03213675, 668.1384587 ],
       [670.37377634, 669.47890183, 668.58432527, 667.69004785],
       [669.92835438, 669.03288409, 668.13771036, 667.24283436],
       [669.48412976, 668.58806451, 667.6922944 , 666.79682063]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [np.indices](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.indices.html) + [np.hypot](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hypot.html)

```
x, y = np.indices((width, height))
np_dist = np.hypot(x - 300, y - 600) # or np.hypot(300 - x, 600 - y)
```